# Quitar basura de textBox con multilinea en VB 2005

Tags: vba, vb6, vb

Tengo un TextBox con multilinea activo, a dicho textbox le tengo asignado el evento KeyUp con la tecla "Enter", con esto pasa el contenido del textbox a una variable global, y esta a su vez se abre desde otra ventana; pero al abrirla en la otra ventana y asignarsela a otro textbox, viene con basura (Lo que puse en el textbox y dos cuadritos)

Sabrían como hacerle un casting a el contenido del primer textbox para que no mande esos cuadritos.

Como se esta enviando desde la forma principal es de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub txtDescripcion_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtDescripcion.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
            If Trim(Replace(txtDescripcion.Text, "'", "")) <> "" Then
                txtDescripcion.Text = Replace(txtDescripcion.Text, "'", "")
                vglParBusq = txtDescripcion.Text
                frmBuscaArticulo.ShowDialog()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Y de la otra forma como se esta recibiendo es así:

```
Private Sub frmBuscaArticulo_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated

   txtBusqueda.Text = vglParBusq 

End Sub
```

La variable vglParBusq es una variable global

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor la pregunta editala y agrega el código

Comment: Hola Javier, no tengo para probar vb en este momento, lo mejor es que agregues el codigo y/o una pantalla para ver el error.
Pero por lo que comentas te recomiendo que mires el formateo de texto o sino la inicializacion el objeto textbox y la asignacion del contenido, el inconveniente debe estar en uno de esos 2 factores, empezaria con el formateo de texto. Un saludo y espero que te sirva para encontrar la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, como había mencionado; a causa del enter, el textbox manda dos cuadros, correspondientes al salto de linea. Lo corregí, sacando la longitud total de la cadena y como siempre son dos caracteres basura (cuadros), hago un mid desde la posición 1 hasta la longitud de la cadena menos esos dos espacios que ocupaban dichos caracteres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]